# Overflow from off-canvas menu conflicts with parallax

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building [this website](http://kuki.im/apc) and I'm facing a very strange problem. For 2 sections in the site i'm using parallax for background pics. It's working if I don't set an overflow rule but It's not working if I'll add. The overflow properties are essential for the off-canvas menu to work properly. I took the code for the off-canvas menu [from here](http://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/sideslide.html).

The elements with the conflict with the overflow are **.container** and **.content-wrap**.

```
html, 
body, 
.container, 
.content-wrap {
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content-wrap {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The code for the parallax is

```
;(function($) {
    $window = $(window);

    $('*[data-type="parallax"]').each(function(){

        var $bgobj = $(this);

        $(window).scroll(function() {

            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

All the js code is in the file **main.js**. I tried to play with the values of **overflow** by removing them and add them elsewhere or wrap all the content in a new element but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are registering the scroll action to the wrong element. What scrolls in this case (after you add your overflow settings) is your content-wrap div, not the browser window. This should work:

```
$(".content-wrap").scroll(function() {
    $('*[data-type="parallax"]').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this);      

        var yPos = -($(".content-wrap").scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

        $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working perfectly now! By the way, I used JS because i thought that it would work. Normally for the parallax effect I used plain css and specifically `background-attachment: fixed`. And again it wasn't working with the overflows enabled. Can we do somthing for this? For using just CSS instead of JS?

Comment: Well, the first thing to try is to somehow modify your CSS solution to take into account the fact that the scrolling element is your content-wrap div. If this doesn't work, I guess I'll need some more details.